# How to calculate and resize images ?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

How can i use this empty space for image (resize images width)?

```
li {
    width: 232px;
    min-width: 232px;
    height: 174px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4px 0 0 4px;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}
li div {
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg);
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #105b63;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps57jpn6/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ps57jpn6/3/)

Assign your width to use the `calc` property on your `li`

CSS:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 3px); /* Added this (Keep in mind I subtracted 3px since you have a margin-left of 3px) */
    /* min-width taken out */
    height: 174px;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none;
    padding: 4px 0 0 4px;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}

li div {
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg);
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #105b63;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes its cute , but its only 3 elements on 1 line .
For example , min-width of card is 100px , device width is 960px , i need to get 9 elements with 100+(60/9)px .

Comment: then change the width to `width: calc(100% / 9 - 3px);`

Comment: Yes , but number 9 is not static ,,, my device show 9 cards , another one show 12 ...